# How does a circular object reference work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, circular-reference

This question arose from an exercise that prompted me to create a circular object such that, in pseudo-code,

```
circular.value === "Hello World"
circular === circular.self
circular.self === circular.self.self
```

...and so on.

I noticed that if I construct an object literal like this,

```
var circular= {
  value: 'Hello World',
  self: circular
}
```

then `circular.self` is `undefined`. However, if I construct an empty object and then assign the values to the properties like this,

```
var circular = {};
circular.value = 'Hello World',
circular.self = circular;
```

then `circular.self` (or `circular.self.self.self.self.self`) is `{ value: 'Hello World', self: [Circular] }`. The same is true no matter what I name the property that is `self` in these examples.

So my specific question is what causes `circular.self` to be `undefined` in the former example while it behaves as I expected in the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var circular` is (because it uses the `var` keyword) hoisted and declares a variable in the current scope as the scope is created (i.e. when the function or global scope is entered). It starts out with a value of `undefined`

`{ ... }` creates a new object and evaluates as a reference to it.

`circular = { ... }` takes that reference and assigns it to `circular`.

The assignment doesn't take place until **after the object literal syntax has been evaluated**.

If you try to read the value of `circular` inside the object literal syntax, it will be `undefined` because you are doing so **before the assignment happens**.

---

In the second example, the object exists and the reference has been assigned to `circular` before you try to read the value of `circular`. The object can then be modified to add a new property whose value is that reference.